# Excel VBA - Copy a Column from Table"TBL_IMPORT" and change value during coping

Tags: excel, vba

I use

```
Sheets"PrepCalc".ListObjects("TBL_PrepCalc").ListColumns.Add ...
```

to copy some whole columns from a "TBL_IMPORT" table on an "Import" Sheet. Works fine.

But there are Columns that need some adjustment and calculation,
like f.e.
Sheet "Import" - Table "TBL_IMPORT" Column "Area" contains the text string "125000000000mm3"
and needs to be placed as '12,5' (as a number) in the column "Area" at the end of the "TBL_PrepCalc" table.

Another column named "width" is also text with f.e "38mm" as value and has  to read in the new column as a number value '38'.

The import table can contain 4500-10000+ rows and 18 columns. ± Half of the columns needs to be changed when copied. What is the best way to work as efficiently as possible?

At first I was thinking to walk through each row, create an universal function that take the "import_table_column" as argument1; the function "Do_the_Area_convert()" that do the math as a argument2; target column as Argument3.

Any suggestions? Being looking for this at this forum and googling around the world, but still haven' found what I'am looking for.

thank you

Comment: You cannot change values during coping you need to paste them and then loop through the values to do your changes. Your question is too broad to give an answer. Please [edit] and show your attempt and ask a question close to your attempt. • You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: You should assign the `Value2` property of your source column to an array; loop through that array to make the required changes, and then assign the `Value2` property of your destination column  to be that (modified) array

Comment: @SpectralInstance, thank you. Thats what i thought, but did hope for a speedy solution. I will try to do what I did mention to write an universal function. If I can't figure it out I will change the question to make it more fit.